# How to prevent conda from printing information when opening terminal?

Tags: ssh, terminal, sftp

How can I prevent conda from displaying information when opening a shell?

I installed  anaconda on a linux server under my account (no admin rights). I then initialized it (conda init tcsh) and all works well. Now I always get some information displayed when launching a shell. It starts with:

```
usage: conda [-h] [-V] command ...
conda is a tool for managing and deploying apllications, environments and packages.
```

This is normal. And expected behaviour.

However, it appears to cause problems when I trying to connect via sftp. (Either over the terminal or FileZilla)

I suspect the conda output in the shell is the reason why I cannot connect to the server via sftp anymore. (When I connect via ssh the same output pops up.)

How can I silence the conda intro message when opening a shell. (I tried conda config --set auto_activate_base false) but that is not enough. That simply stops activating the base environment.)

Comment: If you are using tcsh as your primary shell then add the output of `cat ~/.tcshrc` (not sure if that's the configuration file for tcsh) I guess the conda file is sourced in that file. If your are using another shell such as zsh you should use `cat ~/.zshrc` or if it's bash `cat ~/.bashrc`. For other shells the "shellrc* file should be called similarly.

Comment: Thanks fo trying to help. The file is too long to be shown here in its entirety. This is the output of entering cat ~/.tcshrc on the server. The first line reads: # This is the default standard .cshrc provided to csh users.
Then, the final lines are:
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
if ( -f "/usr/scratch4/MYUSERID/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.csh" ) then
    source "/usr/scratch4/MYUSERID/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.csh"
else
    setenv PATH "/usr/scratch4/MYUSERID/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
endif
# <<< conda initialize <<<

Comment: This leads to a follow-up question. Where can find and how can I access this file? I could try commenting out the conda related block. However I have no admin rights. Not sure how anaconda even modified that file.

Comment: I think `/usr/scratch4/MYUSERID/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.csh` has the message. Better provide the link where you are following that guide to install conda so I can install it too and inspect the files in my computer

Comment: I used: https://arabelatso.github.io/2020/01/09/Install%20Anaconda%20on%20CentOS%20without%20root/ It took VERY long. I aborted the initalization and then did it manually via "conda init tcsh". All OK. So when I launch my terminal I get some info by conda as expected. But this info causes problems when connecting to the server via sftp. Test: ssh MYUSERID@csdata.MYINSTITUTION 'echo hello'. Instead of just hello I get the conda intro info. But sftp does not allow for this. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250379/sftp-on-linux-server-gives-error-received-message-too-long by Kenster.

Comment: I installed it and I didn't get any output as you. So I cannot reproduce your example. Did you try reinstalling conda? Maybe something was not  installed successfully. Also it's weird why conda is using the path `/usr/scratch4/MYUSERID/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.csh` (that should as for room perms perhaps)